# cannot access QML object in C++ code

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10

i'm working on a QML application (blackberry 10) and have a QML file like this:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0    
Page {
        content: Container {
            id: containerID
            Button {
                id: button1
                text: "text"
                onClicked: {
                }
            }
            Label {
                id: label1
                text: "text"
            }
        }
    }
```

now i want to access the `label1` in my c++ code, so i have the following code:

```
#include "app.hpp"

#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>

using namespace bb::cascades;

App::App()
{
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("main.qml");
    //-- setContextProperty expose C++ object in QML as an variable
    //-- uncomment next line to introduce 'this' object to QML name space as an 'app' variable
    //qml->setContextProperty("app", this);

    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootNode<AbstractPane>();

    QObject *labelTest = root->findChild<QObject*>("label1");
    if (labelTest)
        labelTest->setProperty("text", "yes!!");

    Application::setScene(root);
}
```

now i run the app, but the text of the label does not change.

**what is wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.
the QML code:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

//-- create one page with a label and text

Page {
    property alias labelText: label.text      
    content: Container {            
        Label {
            id: label
            text: "Label"
        }  

        Button {
            objectName: "button"
            text: "Button"
        }                               
    }
}
```

and the c++ code:

```
#include "app.hpp"

#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>

using namespace bb::cascades;

App::App()
{
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("main.qml");
    //-- setContextProperty expose C++ object in QML as an variable
    //-- uncomment next line to introduce 'this' object to QML name space as an 'app' variable
    //qml->setContextProperty("app", this);

    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootNode<AbstractPane>();

    root->setProperty("labelText", "yes");

    QObject *newButton = root->findChild<QObject*>("button");
    if (newButton)
        newButton->setProperty("text", "New button text");

    Application::setScene(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is...

QML:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

//-- create one page with a label and text

Page {
    property alias labelText: label.text      
    content: Container {            
        Label {
            id: label
            text: "Label"
            objectName: "label1"
        }  

        Button {
            objectName: "button"
            text: "Button"
        }                               
    }
}
```

C++

```
#include "app.hpp"

#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>

using namespace bb::cascades;

App::App()
{
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("main.qml");
    //-- setContextProperty expose C++ object in QML as an variable
    //-- uncomment next line to introduce 'this' object to QML name space as an 'app' variable
    //qml->setContextProperty("app", this);

    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootNode<AbstractPane>();

    QObject *labelTest = root->findChild<QObject*>("label1");
    if (labelTest)
        labelTest->setText(QString("yes!!"));

    Application::setScene(root);
}
```

But the solution you present is in many ways better.

Comment: I suppose labelTest would have to be casted to Label, am I wrong? Or you could just declare it already: Label *labelTest = root->findChild<Label*>("label1");